# Kinetic JS - children

Tags: kineticjs

I am trying to add lens glass to zoom a specific area of an image, I have a number of layer on the canvas, the project works well if I have just one layer.  I add a temp layer (sorry for having limited experience) using the following:

```
 var wrapper_div = document.getElementById('container1');
    var kinetic_div = wrapper_div.children[0];
    canvaso = kinetic_div.children[0];
    canvaso.setAttribute('id', "panel");
    context = canvaso.getContext('2d');
```

The complete project is at http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/DVSnk/2/, for the demo I left the text layer on.

To check the problem, click on Lens Glass button, then click on the image, the Lens Glass effect works; then please comment stage.add(textlayer), the Lens Glass does not work anymore!  I checked if the temp layer was added using Google developer tool:

```
<div class="kineticjs-content" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 400px; height: 400px;"><canvas width="400" height="400" id="panel" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; position: absolute;"></canvas><canvas width="400" height="400" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; position: absolute;"></canvas></div>
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what is the expected behavior and I can't see the problem.

Comment: Thanks, if you click on the Lens Glass button, then click on the image, it will be enlarged, however if there are two layers, this effect does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing and adding the text layer before and after using the image lens.  Hope this can help someone.